# Reliable way to work out if a given year and quarter are before or after another?

Tags: php, date

E.g. given:

```
$quarter1 = 4;
$year1 = 2011;

$quarter2 = 3;
$year2 = 2012;
```

I need to know that the second set are in the future compared to the first set.

I did think this could be done by literally appending the quarter onto the year. e.g.

```
$qy1 = 20114;
$qy2 = 20123;
// $qy1 < $qy2
```

But I'm sure this is not a reliable way to compare the two. Is there a better, more reliable way?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know, but I thought I would ask just incase! Don't want to get a couple of years into my program knowing its doing it wrong! Plus I thought there might be a robust method using php's date() function. Something less raw. It just looks too simple to be reliable.

Comment: I would say that is a pretty reliable way, as it is just comparing 2 integers that will not get very much bigger for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your method, other than having to do a few string concatenations and typecasting back to int. It could fail, however, if you fail to force the values back to integers, and you're comparing years with different string lengths, e.g.:

```
$date1 = '9994';  // year 999, q4
$date2 = '10011'; // year 1001, q1
```

String 9994 will compare as larger than string 10011.

Purely as an alternative, this would work as well, keeping things purely numeric:

```
$date1 = $year1 + (($quarter1 - 1) / 4);
$date2 = $year2 + (($quarter2 - 1) / 4);
if ($date1 < $date2) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense than mine... because then you get 2011.25 or similar which makes more sense (e.g. literally year 2011 and a quarter). :) I like this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do think this is the best, simplest, and quickest way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($year1<$year2 || $year1==$year2 && $quarter1<$quarter2)
    echo "Date1 is before Date2!";
else
    echo "Date1 is NOT before Date2!";
```

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted, but out of interest why do you add a dash? Surely that'll impede a numerical comparison?

Comment: It is a string comparison, not a numerical comparison.

Comment: This would fail if you were comparing years with different string lengths, e.g. `year 999 v.s. year 1001`. Not too likely to happen, but should be considered.

Comment: I changed it completely, using strings was not necessary.

Comment: @MarcB: I had not considered going so far back in the past. The same problem would have occurred past year 9999. But with numeric types it works with all dates.

Comment: Your new comparison will now fail if you're working with 2012/4 and 2013/1. 4<1 = false.

Comment: I guess date calculations and I aren't good friends today :-( I updated again my answer.